# How can I create a text file that copies ping info from the batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to be able to ping a website such as www.google.com and then have it make a new text file with the results of said ping.

Here is the code of the ping:

```
echo --------------------
echo TESTING CONNECTIVITY
echo --------------------
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 3000
echo.
ping www.google.com -n 5 -w 3000
```

I want that to be in a text file after it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it to a file and use type to display the results also in the console

```
ping www.google.com > result.txt
type results.txt
```

or

```
ping www.google.com | result.txt
```

The latter one will open the result.txt to show the result.

Or put a `type results.txt` after the ping to show the results on the console.

Comment: I've tried that but now it doesn't appear in the actual batch file, which is something I wanted it to do still.

Comment: Alright, i've set it up now but as shown above I have two different pings, but I want the results in the same file. Any help?

Comment: use `>` to create a new file (deletes the existing file). Use `>>` to append to the file.

Comment: Misunderstood the question. But indeed use >>

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pipe the output of the batch file into a text file:

```
mypingbatch.bat >>file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log availabily periodically, schedule the following task:

```
SET IP=www.google.com
SET STATUS=UNAVAILABLE
FOR /F "tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN ('PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%') DO IF "%%h"=="TTL" SET STATUS=%%g
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% %IP% %STATUS% >> ping.%IP%.log
```